# Open and Closing files python code doesn't stop

Tags: python

Trying to shift a load of files from place a to place b (& give them shiny new directories) in python while copying data from a csv file into a metadata text file, using this code.

DirArray holds an array of all the paths of all the files i want to move

```
with open(CSVTestFile, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    with open(MetaDataFile, 'a+') as f:
        i=0
        while i <= len(DirArray):
            for row in reader:
                data = str(row)
                f.write(data+'\n')
                NewPath=WeekPath+'\Test{0}'.format(i+1)
                os.mkdir(NewPath)
                shutil.move(DirArray[i],NewPath)
                i=i+1

        f.close()
    csvfile.close()
```

There probably exists a much more efficient way of doing this so i'd be greatful for pointers there too, but at the moment it does the job of moving the files but the code doesn't stop running? Not an infinite loop as client doesn't crash, but something's still going on, if i stop it it gives the error 'ERROR: execution aborted'. Think my error is in the closing of the file - any thoughts?

Comment: also does anyone know how to copy and paste code without copying it all and individually spacing each line by 4?

Comment: you don"t need to close the files, but that's not an issue either. for the formatting: select and use ctrl+K

Comment: paste your code in to a text editor like Notepad++ and then select it all and indent it (an extra level of indent). Or, paste it in to the WYSIWYG editor here on SO, *select* it, and use the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: Add some strategically placed `print(some important data)` into your code. Especially, monitor what happens to `len(DirArray)` and `i`.

Comment: It's not in the file closing - you don't need it anyway, that's what `with` blocks are for - it's in your loop. You're either attempting to move the opened files, or `i` never gets larger than your `DirArray` (unknown to us from the code presented) length. Also, I assume you want `i=i+1` block outside of the `for` loop... You should paste your stack trace when the error occurs either way.

Comment: many thanks!! I shall try these - debugging has never been my strong suit but i shall endevour to learn!